# How can I run several C# files in the same workspace separately?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

After installing Vscode, I did the following:

1. I opened an empty folder in vscode.
2. Added C# for visual studio code.
3. I entered the `dotnet new console` command in the terminal to create bin, obj folder, .csproj file, and **Program.cs** file.
4. Click .Net Generate Assets for Build and Debug on the Command Palette and generate a .vscode containing launch.json and tasks.json files.
5. I changed the "console" part of the launch.json file to externalTerminal.
6. In my workspacce, I created one more c# file named **test**.

After that, when I tried to run the **test.cs** file, CS0017 error occurred. Later, when I renamed the Main method to something else in the **test** file, the error disappeared. However, when I ran the test file, it was the **Program.cs** file created with the `dotnew new console` command. I searched on Google to find out how to do it and reinstalled Vscode, but couldn't fix it.

Here is the **Program.cs** file and **test.cs** file and launch.json file

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace ProgramFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! Program");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**test.cs**

```
using System;

namespace testFile
{
    class test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! Test");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Vscode.Workspace.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My VSocde**
[My Vscode picture please take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J10pu.png)

Is there a way to create multiple C# files in one workspace and run only the files you want to run each time?

Comment: A C# program can only have one entry point, which by convention is determined by the method signature `static void Main()`. I'm not sure, why would one console app would need two entry points?

Comment: Create a second project if you are making two different programs.

Comment: You dont "run" C# files, you compile them into an executable and run the executable.

Comment: How can I make the second program? I want to work on several programs within the same workspace, but when I create and run a new file like that, only the files created through the "dotnet new console" command will continue to run. If you know how to create two program files in the same workspace and debug or run them whenever necessary, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project  -> Properties -> Application Tab -> Startup object

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
But will you know how to open the Application tab or where is Properties?  This is my first time with VScode. I searched with the VScode application tab, but I can't get any information.

Comment: Look for "Startup object" under .csproj file.

Comment: I want to say I'm really sorry. I don't know if I can't find it, but I can't find what you said. I will put a picture of my VScode in the question. If possible, please let me know which file it is.

Comment: In case it's not there in .csproj file you can add the the property group -> <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>{Namespace.className}</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: Thank you. So what you mean is to add a <StartupObject> {Namespace of the file I want to run. ClassName of the file I want to run} between <PropertyGroup> and </PropertyGroup> in the .csproj file I created with the "" command. Do you mean?

Comment: I added the photo incorrectly, so I added it again, but the file I want to edit after listening to you is Vscode.Workspace.csproj in the photo. The content of VScode.Workspace.csproj is shown in the photo. I'm sorry if I did not understand it, but I would like to ask one last question about which file should be modified. Thank you for your kind help. And I'm really sorry.

Comment: Here is my VSCode photo link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/J10pu.png

Comment: Yeah looks like the the right file, my file looks like this <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>ConsoleApp4.Test.Test</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Comment: Sorry... I think I did something wrong
My .csproj file 

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>
      {Vscode_Workspace.Program}
    </StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

I'm wondering about what is 'ConsoleApp4' and what did I do wrong

Comment: ConsoleApp4.Test is the namespace of the class that holds 'Main' method in my case Test class so {Namespace.Class} becomes {ConsoleApp4.Test.Test}

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.  I'm also sorry to keep bothering you.  But I don't understand what is  namespace of the class.  The namespace name that I declared in the test file is testfile, and the class name is test. I think {testfile.test} is innocent. Where can I find something like your ConsoleApp4? And how should I write code?

Comment: Sorry... How could I get my namespace of the class in the test file